# How to inject dependency originating from suspend function with Hilt?

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, dagger-hilt

I am trying to implement encrypted Rooms database, and in method for getting encryption key from DataStore I have to use several suspend function which makes method itself suspend. But how should I use this method inside Dagger Hilt module to get the key?

This is the method for getting encryption key

```
 suspend fun getDbKey(): CharArray {
      context.dataBaseKeyDataStore.data.map {
        it[PREFERENCES_KEY]
      }.first()?.let {
        return  it.toCharArray()
      }

      val dbKey = createNewKey()
      context.dataBaseKeyDataStore.edit {
        it[PREFERENCES_KEY] = dbKey
      }
      return dbKey.toCharArray()
```

}

I need to inject database DAO with Hilt, and I have to call suspend function inside Hilt provide method.

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
class FileDataBaseModule {
  @Provides
  @Singleton
  fun provideChannelDao(fileDataBase: FileDataBase): MyFileDao {
    return fileDataBase.myFileDao()
  }

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  fun provideAppDatabase(
    @ApplicationContext context: Context,
    databaseKeyStorage: DatabaseKeyStorage
  ): FileDataBase {
    val dbKey = runBlocking {  databaseKeyStorage.getDbKey() }
    return FileDataBase.create(context, dbKey)
  }
}
```

However, I heard so much warnings against using runBlocking method in production code, and I'm not sure that I solve this problem correctly. Should I really use runBlocking{} to get value from suspend function or there are any other ways to do what I need to?